# How to determine whether removing a given cycle will disconnect a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have seen ways to detect a cycle in a graph, but I still have not managed to find a way to detect a "bridge-like" cycle. So let's say we have found a cycle in a connected (and undirected) graph. How can we determine whether removing this cycle will disconnect the graph or not? By removing the cycle, I mean removing the edges in the cycle (so the vertices are unaffected).

One way to do it is clearly to count the number of components before and after the removal. I'm just curious to know if there's a better way.

If there happens to be an established algorithm for that, could anyone please point me to a related work/paper/publication?

Comment: `Articulation Point` in a graph will be of help.

Comment: Refer [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-undirected-graph/)

Comment: @AakashBarapatre I believe that algorithm only finds a cycle, but it does not determine whether removing it would disconnect a graph.

Comment: Modify that algorithm such that after removing an edge it still checks if there is any other edge which forms a cycle

Comment: Are you deleting the cycle vertices or just the edges?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat pretty sure vertices, because if it was only edges, you can simply find a cycle that is not a self-loop and it will be the answer.

Comment: @Wayne also, do you need all cycles or one? I can't really think of anything besides finding all cycles, removing them and finding the number of components that are left after removing.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 Unless we're, e.g., deleting a simple cycle from K5?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat sorry, you are right, that I didn't think about. But doesn't finding all cycles and checking them one by one work? (checking by removing and seeing how many components we have after removal).

Comment: @paulpaul1076 It does, but there could be exponentially many.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I delete only the edges.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 Actually what I need is the following: let's say we have found a cycle in a graph, how can we check whether removing it will disconnect the graph? (I probably phrased my question in a bad way earlier - sorry about that. I've edited my post to make it clearer.) One way to do it is, as you mentioned, count the number of components. But I'm just curious to know if there is a better way. I saw your post earlier about articulation points, and I think that looks interesting.

Comment: @Wayne thanks for clarifying, I deleted my earlier posts because Kolmar pointed to a graph that my approach didn't work for.

Comment: @Wayne honestly, now that you are saying that cycle edges are given in input, you can just remove them and check in linear time how many components you have. So I guess my question is, do you want to find such a cycle, or is it already given to you?

Comment: @paulpaul1076 A cycle in a graph is regarded as given here, and then I need to check whether removing it will disconnect the graph. The thing is I'm going to check that for every cycle (found by whatever algorithm) in a graph. I mentioned that a cycle was given just to avoid unnecessary complication (now I'm not sure I did avoid that) - I thought once we knew a method for one cycle, I could just repeat that for all cycles in a graph.

Comment: And because I'm going to deal with many cycles, it would be great to know an algorithm that is more efficient than directly counting the components (if such algorithm exists at all).

Comment: @Wayne https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peripheral_cycle found a related concept. At first I thought we could rule out all peripheral cycles, but then I realized that removal or peripheral cycles implies removal of vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the naive algorithm, complexity wise I don't think there's a more efficient way of doing the check.

- Start with your list of edges (*cycleEdges*)
- Get the set of vertices within *cycleEdges* (*cycleVertices*)

  - If a vertex in *cycleVertices* only contains edges that are part of *cycleEdges* return FALSE
- For Each vetex In *cycleVertices*

  - Recursively follow vertex's edges that are not in *cycleEdges* (avoid already visited vertices)

    - If a vertex is reached that is not in *cycleVertices* add it to te set *outsideVertices* (stop recursively searching this path)
  - If only vertices that are in *cycleVertices* have been reached Return FALSE
- If *outsideVertices* contains 1 element Return TRUE
- Choose a vertex in *outsideVertices* and remove it from *outsideVertices*

  - Recursively follow that vertex's edges that are not in *cycleEdges* (avoid already visited vertices) (favor choosing edges that contain a vertex in *outsideVertices* to improve running time for large graphs)

    - If a vertex is reached that is in *outsideVertices* remove it from *outsideVertices*

      - If *outsideVertices* is empty Return TRUE
- Return FALSE

Comment: So, cycleEdges are edges of all cycles or one cycle?

Comment: @paulpaul1076 - cycleEdges represent the edges in the current cycle we are testing. The OP want to take an already found cycle an see if it can be removed while still preserving the graph's connctedness.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for E+V.
You can get all bridges in your graph for E+V by dfs + dynamic programming.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bridge-in-a-graph

Save them (just make boolean[E], and make true.
Then you can say for O(1) the edge is bridge or not.
You can just take all edges from your cycle and verify that it is bridge.

Answer (score 0):

Vish's mentions articulation points which is definitely in the right direction. More can be said though. Articulation points can be found via a modified DFS algorithm that looks something like this:

Execute DFS, assigning each number with its DFS number (e.g. the number of nodes visited before it). When you encounter a vertex that has already been discovered compare its DFS number to the current vertex and you can store a LOW number associated with this vertex (e.g. the lowest DFS number that this node has "seen"). As you recurse back to the start vertex, you can compare the parent vertex with the child's LOW number. As you're recursing back, if a parent vertex ever sees a child's low number that is greater than or equal to its own DFS number, then that parent vertex is an articulation point.

I'm using "child" and "parent" here as descriptors a lot because in the DFS tree we have to consider a special case for the root. If it ever sees a child's low number that is greater than or equal to its own DFS number and it has two children in the tree, then the first vertex is an articulation.

[Here's a useful art. point image](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/)

Another concept to be familiar with, especially for undirected graphs, is biconnected components, aka any subgraph whose vertices are in a cycle with all other vertices.

[Here's a useful colored image with biconnected components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTKKW.png)

You can prove that any two biconnected components can only share one vertex max; two "shared" vertices would mean that the two are in a cycle, as well as with all the other vertices in the components so the two components are actually one large component. As you can see in the graph, any vertex shared by two components (has more than one color) is an articulation point. Removing the cycle that contains any articulation point will thus disconnect the graph.

Comment: I can't find the original paper for the modified DFS algorithm but finding articulation points in a graph has a lot of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as in a cycle from any vertex *x* can be reached any other vertex *y* and vice-verse, then it's a strongly connected component, so we can contract a cycle into a single vertex that represents the cycle. The operation can be performed for *O(n+m)* using DFS. Now, we can apply DFS again in order to check whether the contracted cycles are articulation vertices, if they are, then removing them will disconnect a graph, else not. Total time is *2(n+m) = O(n+m)*